# Number Theory (Polynomials) Find The Remainder?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

A polynomial $f(x) = x^{50} + 3x^{49} + 3x + 12$ when divided by $x - a$,  it leaves remainder $3$ & when its quotient is further divided by $x - b$ it leaves remainder $5$, also when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2 - ( b + a)x + ab$ the remainder is $x + 6$. Find $a$?

Comment: The Answer "a" might come in terms of x as well

Comment: Where this polynomial belong to? You are considering integer coefficients or complex?

Answer (score 2):

So by Remainder theorem, $f(a)=3$ and $f(x)=g(x)(x-a)(x-b)+(x+6)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. Using the first result in the second, you immediately get …

Comment: So, by combining the above two answers we get the value of $a$ free from $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$P=x^{50}+3x^{49}+3x+12=x^{49}(x+3)+3(x+3)+3=k(x-a)+3$

So the quotient k is:

$k=\frac{(x^{49}+3)(x+3)}{x-a}$

⇒$\frac{(x^{49}+3)(x+3)}{x-a}=k_1(x-b)+5$

⇒$(x^{49}+3)(x+3)=k_1(x-a)(x-b)+5(x-a)$

⇒$p=(x^{49}+3)(x+3)+3=k_1(x-a)(x-b)+5(x-a)+3$

Therefore:

$5(x-a)+3=x+6$ ⇒ $a=\frac{4x-3}{5}$